# How to display a DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I want to load a DropDownList with possible Paises from my database.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using Backend;
using Backend.Models;

namespace Frontend_UI_Web.Administrativos
{
    public partial class Ciudad : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PaisRepository paisRepo = new PaisRepository();
            LoadPaises(paisRepo);

            CiudadRepository ciudadRepo = new CiudadRepository();            
        }

        private void LoadPaises(PaisRepository paisRepo)
        {
            //FindAll() returns a collection IQueryable<Pais>!
            var Paises = paisRepo.FindAll().AsEnumerable();
            uiddlPais.DataSource = Paises;
            uiddlPais.DataBind();
        }

        protected void uibtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Any guidance? If I run this code the dropdownlist loads 5 items, which is correct since I have 5 paises. But the names aren't displayed correctly.

Comment: Can you define 'Paises'?

Comment: Your question would get more attention from those who can answer it if you had included "asp.net" in the tags.

Comment: @BG100 Google Translate says it's "Countries"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to set the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` properties of the DropDownList so that it knows which properties of each `Pais` object it should bind to.

Supposing that `Pais` looks like

```
class Pais
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

then you'd want `DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id"`.

Answer (score 0):

Set DataTextField and DataValueField?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are forgetting to set the `DataValueField` and `DataTextField` properties of your drop-down list. Then you can have your sweet little paisies!

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify which members of your `Paise` class you want to display as Text and Value fields.

Something like this would work:

```
uiddlPais.DataSource = Paises;
uiddlPais.DataTextField = "Name";
uiddlPais.DataValueField = "Id";
uiddlPais.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

u will need to set DataTextField  and DataValueField  property of dropdownlist

DataTextField is shown to user and DataValueField does not shown. It works in code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you defined which properties you want your `DropDownList` to bind to using the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` properties.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="uiddlPais" runat="server"
    DataTextField="TheFieldWithTheTextYouWantToDisplay"
    DataValueField="TheFieldWithTheValueYouWantAttached" />
```

Also I see a problem in your `Page_Load`.  You should be wrapping the initalizing of you `DropDownList` in a `if (!IsPostBack)` check or else you will be rebinding it with every postback and then your `uibtnSubmit` will not be able to read the selected value since you would have reloaded the `DropDownList` before the click even was reached.  So it should look like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {   
        PaisRepository paisRepo = new PaisRepository();   
        LoadPaises(paisRepo);
    }
}
```